# Why do appliances use complicated circuits to convert AC to DC instead of just using a battery?

Tags: batteries, rectifier

What I'm trying to say is why huge rectifier circuits are needed just for converting AC to DC.

Why can't the rectifier be replaced with a battery and a battery charger? Since batteries can supply a steady DC current, there wont be a need for all the necessary components in conversion like multiple capacitors etc. Etc.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your question opens up safety, weight, cost, size, power, utility for use, and still more issues -- and all of those to a host of appliances that span from hair curlers to kitchen oven/stoves. In short, you'd need a book, or an encyclopedia set, to help you understand the balancing trade-offs. Do you think you could narrow this question down, a bit?

Comment: Decisions about the characteristics of products offered for sale are made based on consumer demand, market forces, political forces etc. There are limitations that are based on electrical engineering theory and design principles, but the question is not really about that and thus not suitable to be answered here. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about market forces and consumer demand rather than electrical engineering theory and design.

Comment: Battery charger is not less complicated that AC to DC converter. This is the primary fallacy built-in to your question. A battery charger is actually more complicated than a simple AC-DC converter.

Comment: Batteries are expensive.

Comment: `Why can't the rectifier be replaced with a battery and a battery charger? ` ... you have not really thought this through before posting, have you? .... the rectifier would be moved to the charger

Comment: The battery charger is a huge rectifier circuit, plus battery charge controller, so...

Answer (score 2):

As mkeith mentions, the core premise of this question is incorrect. An AC battery charger effectively incorporates an AC/DC converter inside it, as well as a load of other circuitry. You would be taking away your existing AC/DC converter, and adding another one with the same (or greater) power rating, as well as extra circuitry, plus a battery on top.